# Zone is not defined for NgZone angular2@2.0.0-beta.0

Tags: angular

When upgrading to `angular2@2.0.0-beta.0` from the alpha version, I am getting the following error when building.

`zone is not defined for ng zone`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, it seems that importing the browser version of Zone.js is also a workaround.

In browser:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
```

Extract from webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'zone.js/dist/zone',
        // instead of 'zone.js'
    ],
};
```

I wanted to add as comment, but don't have the reputation yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it multiple ways.
If you are using imports add the following line to the startup script.

```
import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';
```

It registers to the global object and patches the browser.
A second way is as mentioned above to include it in HTML:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
```

The third one is to enable production mode, it only gave me errors when long stack traces were enabled.

```
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
enableProdMode();
```

You should call `enableProdMode` before `bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Zone is not defined in the following files in angular2@2.0.0-beta.0.

- angular2\es6\dev\src\core\zone\ng_zone.js
- angular2\es6\prod\src\core\zone\ng_zone.js
- angular2\src\core\zone\ng_zone.js
- angular2\ts\src\core\zone\ng_zone.js
- angular2\bundles\angular2-all.umd.dev.js
- angular2\bundles\angular2-all.umd.js angular2\bundles\angular2.dev.js
- angular2\bundles\angular2.js angular2\bundles\web_worker\ui.dev.js
- angular2\bundles\web_worker\worker.dev.js

Changing the line of code in the TS file

`angular2\ts\src\core\zone\ng_zone.ts@352`

`Zone.longStackTraceZone, {onError: function(e) { ngZone._notifyOnError(this, e); }});`

To

`zone.longStackTraceZone, {onError: function(e) { ngZone._notifyOnError(this, e); }});`

Notice the capitalization change. There is no Zone, but a parameter zone. This temporarily fixes the build issue, but may not be the correct fix.

Some others have mentioned changing from dev mode to production mode is also a work around. Have not tested this.

This issue is being tracked on github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5998) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6007).

A pull request for the fix for this issue is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5995).